# Install4j: how to return to a previous FromComponent (especially in console) in the same screen

Tags: install4j

I have a screen where I have two password field `FormComponents`. One is for taking user password and another is for confirming the password. Now, especially in console, if the user fails to confirm the password, I would like to go back to the previous `FormComponent` which is the first component for asking password. In `Context`, I have only found methods for going back to a certain `Screen`. Is it possible for me to go back to the previous or a certain `FormComponent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. For this kind of control I would recommend to use a "Console handler" form component to specify the logic yourself. Place all other form components into a vertical group and set its visibility script to

```
!context.isConsole()
```

so they will not be displayed in console mode.